Why does `dependency:tree -Dexcludes=a.b.c` not always exclude a.b.c?
I want to quickly see a list of relevant module dependencies. Using dependency:tree, I want to filter out internal and optional dependencies and their respective transitive dependencies.
For this, I use the following command
mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=runtime \
  -Dexcludes={dependencies}

However, some of the dependencies I exclude are still in the output tree and I would like to know if there is something I am doing wrong
Example using spring-ws at 4.0.11, sub module spring-ws-core
Without excludes, I can see dependencies for jakarta.mail-api and jaxb-runtime:
mvn -o dependency:tree -Dscope=runtime \
  | grep -E '(jakarta.mail-api|jaxb-runtime)'                                    
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] +- jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:jar:2.1.3:compile

Excluding jakarta.mail-api using just the groupId:artifactId seems to work
mvn -o dependency:tree -Dscope=runtime \
  -Dexcludes=jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api \
  | grep -E '(jakarta.mail-api|jaxb-runtime)'
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.5:runtime

However, I cannot say this about jaxb-runtime
mvn -o dependency:tree -Dscope=runtime \
  -Dexcludes=org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime \
  | grep -E '(jakarta.mail-api|jaxb-runtime)'
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] +- jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:jar:2.1.3:compile

The filtering seems to work only on specific dependencies, excluding both only filters out jakarta.mail-api which also worked if only individually excluded
mvn -o dependency:tree -Dscope=runtime \
  -Dexcludes=jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api,org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime \
  | grep -E '(jakarta.mail-api|jaxb-runtime)'
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.5:runtime

There are a few dependencies that seem to work and others that do not work at all. I do not see a pattern here. I could just filter them out using grep -v but this would leave me with the transitive dependencies.
Note: I see the same results running without a specific version (which resolves to 2.8) and running with 3.8.0, the latest version at the time of writing, via
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.8.0:tree ...


Which version of the maven-dependency-plugin do you use? Have you defined the most recent version in your pom.xml?

I originally ran with 2.8, but just tried with 3.8.0 and see the exact same output. I'll add this to the question

I would say it looks like a bug... please report the issues with examples https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ (for JIRA location)...

Thank you @khmarbaise - I have just added a comment to an already existing issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-927. It seems to not have been picked up in more than 5 months.
